# Contain figure image within borders

Tags: html, css

The following code

```
<figure style="">

    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0tkb.png">

</figure>
```

What should the style parameter be above so that [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0tkb.png) is proportionally resized but not cropped to stay within a thumbnail type 250*250 square.

PS: The following crops the image:

```
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: thick;
object-fit: contain;
contain: content;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give `width: 100%` and `height: auto` properties to your image to make it responsive. It will resize to fill its parent measures.

Comment: Indeed, the following img style worked as expected:
```
    img {
       max-width: 100%;
       max-height: 100%;
    }
```
Still prefer to achieve it with just figure style.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what `object-fit` does.
The `object-fit` property relies on the image's dimensions rather than its parent's. You need to set both `width` and `height` for it to work and you have to apply `object-fit` to the image itself, not to `<figure>`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```html
<figure style="text-align: center; width: 250px; height: 250px; border-style: solid; border-width: thick; object-fit: contain; contain: content;">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0tkb.png" style="height: 100%;">
</figure>
```